# such lots of OR so lots of

Tags: sentence-structure

which is the correct structure and why?
I found it while I was reading Cambridge Grammar in use intermediate on page no. 204
it says 'such' should precede 'a lot of'. so can we use 'such' before 'lots of'?

Comment: We can just about use ***such*** as a kind of "intensifier" for ***a lot of***, in something like *Rover eats **such a lot of** dog food! I can hardly afford to keep him properly fed!* But that's not common - we're much more likely to use ***so much*** in such contexts. And I can't think of *any* contexts where ***such lots of*** would be likely. Please provide some more detail, such as the *actual example sentences* Cambridge Grammar uses to illustrate whatever point they're making there.

Comment: _Such lots of_ is not idiomatic English, and _so lots of_ even less so. If you want to use _such_ you have to say _a lot of_. (Ngrams produced some results, but all seemed to refer to 'lots' (measured quantities) of land or goods of some kind.

Comment: I have voted to close.  I guess that Kate is on the right tracks, but the question needs work to be clearly answered.  What are the actual examples?  If CGiU says the expression is "such a lot of", why do you doubt this?

Comment: I'm actually guessing a stray word "it" in "I found it" has given the impression that the OP encountered the phrase but in fact only found the advice that "'such' should precede 'a lot of,'" and is curious about the plural. Btw, part of the reason it doesn't work is that "such a" is a phrase together.